# React-query, query doesn't update arguments

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I use the `react-query` library to get my data.
When the user changes, I would love it if the previous user data was removed automatically & new data was fetched.

This does, not happen though, the api gets called a couple times more with the old userId, and only after 1 or 2 times re-focussing on the app, it will fetch the data with the proper new `userId`.
Here is the hook:
When I log some info in the `getData` function, I can see it being called a couple times with the old userId after logging out.

```
export default function useData() {
    const {user} = useAuth();
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    useEffect(() => {
        queryClient.removeQueries('data')
        queryClient.invalidateQueries()
    }, [user]);
    return useQuery('data', () => getData(user!.uid), {
        enabled: !!user,
    })
}
```

Does anyone know how I can remove all data when my `user` changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All dependencies of your query should be in the query key, because react-query automatically refetches when the key changes. This is also in the docs [here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key).

In your case, this means adding the user id:

```
useQuery(
  ['data', user?.uid],
  () => getData(user!.uid),
  {
    enabled: !!user,
  }
)
```

For clearing up old cache entries, I would possibly suggest setting `cacheTime: 0` on your query, which means they will be garbage collected as soon as the last observer unmounts. Calling `queryClient.removeQueries` manually is also an option.